# Firefox 21: Error Console Doesn't Display Error Messages

Tags: firefox, javascript, console

**Windows 7 Professional**

**Firefox 21.0**

Hi,

The error console ( Tools > Web Developer > Error Console ) in Firefox is not displaying Javascript error messages under any circumstances.

I get these messages in my error console when starting up a fresh session:

```
Could not read chrome manifest 'file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Mozilla%20Firefox/chrome.manifest'.

Could not read chrome manifest 'file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Mozilla%20Firefox/distribution/bundles/%7BD19CA586-DD6C-4a0a-96F8-14644F340D60%7D/chrome.manifest'.

Timestamp: Friday June 14 11:35:21 AM
Warning: Unknown property 'align-self'.  Declaration dropped.
Source File: resource://gre-resources/ua.css
Line: 45, Column: 12
Source Code:
  align-self: inherit; /* needed for "align-self" to work on table flex items */

Timestamp: Friday June 14 11:35:21 AM
Warning: Unknown property 'order'.  Declaration dropped.
Source File: resource://gre-resources/ua.css
Line: 46, Column: 7
Source Code:
  order: inherit;   /* needed for "order" to work on table flex items */

Timestamp: Friday June 14 11:35:23 AM
Warning: XUL box for _moz_generated_content_after element contained an inline #text child, forcing all its children to be wrapped in a block.
Source File: chrome://browser/content/browser.xul
Line: 0

Timestamp: Friday June 14 11:35:23 AM
Error: this.docShell is null
Source File: chrome://global/content/bindings/browser.xml
Line: 323
```

I looked in my installation directory.  Sure enough, there is no chrome.manifest file at either path.   Should I try to get such a file or just do a reinstall with a fresh profile?

Comment: Did you *try* reinstalling? You don't necessarily even need to delete your profile to fix the first error. Also, on my system, chrome.manifest isn't in the same directory as firefox.exe; it's in the `browser` subdirectory, and my JS console works fine. So that particular error message may be a red herring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reset Firefox to factory defaults by going to
Help > Trouble Shooting > Reset Firefox

That cleared up the problem.

I then added preferences back one by one until the Error Console broke again.

Choosing "Never Remember History" in Tools > Options > Privacy  recreated the problem.